# Which certification exam in sun takes struts2 and hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, struts2

I am done with my scjp6 exam last week.I got 100%.Now i am thinking of giving scwcd.I know sevlet,jsp,struts2 framework and hibernate.I wanted to know is there any specific certification in sun for hibernate and struts2?

Comment: Nope, there isn't. Those are open source projects, not official Oracle JEE specifications.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt in that!!!
Sun certification includes only JSP and servlets.

Alternatively, Sun certification has Exam on Persistence:

http://education.oracle.com/pls/web_prod-plq-dad/db_pages.getpage?page_id=434

Answer (score 0):

Servlet, JSP and JPA (used for data storage) are covered in the SCEA exam (now: Oracle Certified Master, Java EE 5 Enterprise Architect).

This is an exam to check your architecture skills. Even when Hibernate is not directly covered , JPA annotations are checked. These annotations can be used with Hibernate too. So proving your skills with JPA proves somehow your skills with Hibernate.

Please have in mind, this is a very top-level exams. You'll need to know lots about everything. It is also consisting of three parts.

More here: http://education.oracle.com/pls/web_prod-plq-dad/db_pages.getpage?page_id=326

Struts 2 is not covered by the exams. But you could prove your web skills with this exam:

Oracle Certified Expert, Java Platform, Enterprise Edition 6, JavaServer Pages and Servlet Developer
http://education.oracle.com/pls/web_prod-plq-dad/db_pages.getpage?page_id=430

It focuses on Servlets, JSP and such.

You could also compare it with that one:
Oracle Certified Professional, Java EE 5 Web Component Developer
http://education.oracle.com/pls/web_prod-plq-dad/db_pages.getpage?page_id=322

I am sorry, but I can't tell what the actual difference between these two is.

The exam for persistence has already be named in this thread.

If I were you - shortly after the SCJP - I would NOT go with the Architects exam. In your case I would directly head over to the JSP/Servlet related exam. This is a very good starting point to learn about containers and get used to the Java EE world in general. After all, you can see immediately what you have developed - that is motivating. While persistence is really important, it is a little tricky if you do not know anything about containers.

Good luck!
Christian